# Larger thumbnails in Channel Images Tile view?

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

I did a CSS hack (that Brad recommended) to make the thumbnails in the entry screen larger. I'm wondering if there's a similar hack I can make to make the thumbs in the Tile view larger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the config over option of:

$config['ci_image_preview_size'] = '50px';

There is a list of config override options in our ci_config.php.

Located in /third_party/channel_images/config.

You have to add it to your main config.php file for the system.

Comment: Just so it's more clear for me, are you saying I need to add `$config['ci_image_preview_size'] = '50px';` to the EE config.php file and does it matter where in that file? Do I need to also change this setting in the ci_config.php? Also, is it possible to tell CI to not crop the preview images?

Comment: Just put it in the main config.php only and anywhere in the first part is fine. I usually put my stuff right after the default install options.  CI should use the image of whatever you chose in the field settings. If you choose a cropped version, it will show a cropped version.

Comment: The good news is I got the cropping of previews stopped, thanks! However with the other thing -- trying to increase the size of the preview images in Tile view -- didn't have any effect at all. I put `$config['ci_image_preview_size'] = '250px';` into my EE config file, but the preview size didn't change in Tile view and also the images were distorted because they had the same dimensions. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I apologize the tile view size can not be increased as things currently are. You can increase the size in table view but not tile view. You would need to hack it for tile view.

Comment: Just to follow up, does adding `$config['ci_image_preview_size'] = '250px';` to config.php do the same thing as the sort of hack you mentioned to me before (changing the width in hbs-templates.js)? Also, I think a nice enhancement would be to make it possible to use categories with Tile view... not sure if there's much demand for that, but a handful of my clients would be happier with it.